# Node Middleware Without Express

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm building an AWS Lambda Server to Integrate with API Gateway and I'm unable to expose the server so that I can hook it into Express. I'm wondering if anyone knows a best practice for using middleware without Express.

Here is my code.

```
    var jobs = require('./jobs');
    var http = require('http')

    const server = http.createServer()

    server.on('request', (req, res) => {


    //I want to be able to add a function here that executes all of the middleware that I specify.

    const { headers, method, url } = req;

    let body = [];

    if(url)

            enableCors(res);
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

            const resBody = { headers, method, url, body };

            res.write(JSON.stringify(resBody));
            res.end();
    }).listen(8080);
```

I want to have something similar to Express where I can write something like this and the server will know to search that directory for my routes.

```
server.use('/api', require('./api'))
```

Comment: ***"unable to expose the server so that I can hook it into Express"*** makes no sense to me.  You have a `server` object.  That's all you need to hook in Express.   `const app = require('express')(); http.createServer(app)` will hook Express into your server.

Comment: Or you can hook it in after the fact with `const app = require('express')(); 
 server.on('request', app);`

Comment: Otherwise, if you want use existing Express middleware, then you have to write your own middleware scheme that is compatible with the calling convention and `req`, `res` object setup that Express does for you.  That's doable (though would probably require a lot of study of the Express code to include everything it does), but it's probably way easier to find a way to plug Express (which is JUST an event handler) into what you already have.

Comment: Using `express` on AWS Lambda is not best practice in the first place. Running `express` on Lambda exists in order to help port _existing_ express apps to Lambda. But if you're writing something new, better do it the Lambda way.

Comment: I think the point is being missed somehow. The point is that it is impossible to use Express with Lambda functions because the request comes through with different parameters. `(event, context, callback)` and even if it was possible, I don't want to because API Gateway does most of the work that Express does anyways. I simply wanted to find a way to mimic the AWS Lambda function parameters on my local machine for version control purposes. This way instead of having to maintain each individual Lamda function, I would instead be maintaining the entire infrastructure locally.

Comment: @MiguelCoder I now understand what you mean. I do the same thing with my projects. Your question does not mention those though and so we thought you want to use `express` IN AWS Lambda when all you want to do is to simulate API Gateway with `express`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since what you want is a local simulation of API Gateway using `express`, here's what I'm using for my projects.

This does not require `serverless` or `claudiajs`.

I also always just use Lambda Proxy integration so it's simpler.

Something like this...

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express')

// Two different Lambda handlers
const { api } = require('../src/api')
const { login } = ('../src/login')

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

// route and their handlers
app.post('/login', lambdaProxyWrapper(login))
app.all('/*', lambdaProxyWrapper(api))

app.listen(8200, () => console.info('Server running on port 8200...'))


function lambdaProxyWrapper(handler) {
  return (req, res) => {
    // Here we convert the request into a Lambda event
    const event = {
      httpMethod: req.method,
      queryStringParameters: req.query,
      pathParameters: {
        proxy: req.params[0],
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
    }

    return handler(event, null, (err, response) => {
      res.status(response.statusCode)
      res.set(response.headers)

      return res.json(JSON.parse(response.body))
    })
  }
}
```

Then, run it with `nodemon` so it watches the files and reloads as necessary.

```
nodemon --watch '{src,scripts}/**/*.js' scripts/server.js
```

Comment: This is a great solution and it does answer my original question better than my own answer so I'm going to accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide an example without express at all?

Comment: 2 years late to the answer but you could use the following script and replace the express parts. I haven't refined the code but it works well. Hopefully this will nudge you in the direction you wanted.

https://github.com/kimathie/httpserver-nodejs/blob/master/server.js

Answer (score 1):

Node `http` has no concept of middleware.  You either need to create your own middleware chain, or else use something like `express`.  If, for some reason, you don't want to use `express` (not clear from your question why this is the case)  you could always choose to use [connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect), which `express` is based on.

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');

var app = connect();

// gzip/deflate outgoing responses
var compression = require('compression');
app.use(compression());

// store session state in browser cookie
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
app.use(cookieSession({
    keys: ['secret1', 'secret2']
}));

// parse urlencoded request bodies into req.body
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// respond to all requests
app.use((req, res) => {
  const { headers, method, url } = req;

  let body = [];

  if(url)
    enableCors(res);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

  const resBody = { headers, method, url, body };

  res.write(JSON.stringify(resBody));
  res.end();
});

//create node.js http server and listen on port
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

Comment: In my question, I stated that I am not able to use any kind of Router because I cannot expose the http Server to my Lambda Function. I'm simply building this portion so that I can expose my local implementation to a similar architecture.

Comment: What you're saying makes no sense.  You're not "exposing" your server to express; express decorates the in-memory server object.  That's not changed by being on Lambda.  If you're not comfortable with that, you can always use the serverless library: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express

Comment: Ok well I still can't use express because AWS Lambda doesn't use express and I don't want to maintain an external server just to call a lambda function. lambda functions have (event, context, and callback) parameters passed to their handlers instead of (req, res) parameters. So, technically I am not able to expose my server to the express API because the request is already being handled by API Gateway.

Comment: I just want to make a local implementation that mimics the architecture and isn't too convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to simulate a local Lambda and API Gateway using the [serverless](https://serverless.com/) framework with the [serverless-offline](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline) plugin and following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/a-man-with-no-server/running-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-locally-serverless-offline-3c64b3e54772).

This builds a dockerized container that allows me to create my endpoints locally using the `serverless.yml` file in the following format.

```
functions:
  getDataFromBackend:
    handler: handler.handlerFunc
    events:
      - http:
          path: /api/path/to/endpoint/{param}
          method: get
          cors: true
```

Then I after I run this command...

`sls offline start -r us-east-1 --noTimeout`

I get endpoints that I can hit by adding their respective functions to the handler.js file.

These functions receive the `(event, context, callback)` functions just like a Lambda function would.

Now I can build for serverless locally :)

I hope this helps someone